# Make Button change content of Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I'm trying to make the selected elements of a Listbox move to another Listbox on the press of a Button. However, I don't understand how to make the button know to which listboxes it is getting and sending data to.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MoveItems(ttk.Button):
#the button should move things from the origin listbox to the destiny
#listbox
    def __init__(self, parent, origin, destiny, label):
        ttk.Button.__init__(self, parent, text = label)
        self.parent = parent
        self.origin = origin #is this correct?
        self.destiny = destiny
        self.command = self.moveToDestiny

    def moveToDestiny(self):
        selected_items = self.origin.curselection()
        selected = [self.origin.get(i) for i in selected_items]
        self.destiny.list_update(selected)


class ListOfThings(tk.Listbox):
#here are my listboxes
#list_update adds a list to the listbox
        def __init__(self, parent, list_to_show):
            tk.Listbox.__init__(self, parent, selectmode = tk.EXTENDED)
            self.list_to_show = list_to_show
            self.parent = parent
            self.list_update(list_to_show)

        def list_update(self, list):
            for item in list:
                self.insert(tk.END, item)


class SelectFromList(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        list1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
        list2 = ["D", "E", "F"]

        self.leftList = ListOfThings(self, list1)
        self.rightList = ListOfThings(self, list2)
        self.moveRight = MoveItems(self, self.leftList, self.rightList, "-->")

        self.leftList.pack(side = "left")
        self.moveRight.pack(side = "left")
        self.rightList.pack(side = "right")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    SelectFromList(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

I'm not sure if the `__init__` of my MoveItems button really keeps track of the origin and destiny listboxes. I tried to just print the `selected` items, but nothing shows up on the Terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `self.command = self.moveToDestiny` will do what you want. We know that `command` is the name of a parameter in the Button's `init` method, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the value is subsequently stored in a `command` attribute.

Try specifying `command` when you call `Button.__init__`.

```
class MoveItems(ttk.Button):
#the button should move things from the origin listbox to the destiny
#listbox
    def __init__(self, parent, origin, destiny, label):
        ttk.Button.__init__(self, parent, text = label, command=self.moveToDestiny)
```

Now your button should successfully add items to the list box on the right.

---

I bet you also want the selected items to be removed from the left box. You'll have to make another `ListOfThings` method that *removes* items from the list. Something like:

```
    def list_remove(self, items_to_remove):
        items = self.get(0, tk.END)
        remaining_items = [item for item in items if item not in items_to_remove]
        self.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.list_update(remaining_items)
```

(Probably not the best approach, but this is just an example)

Then you can call it in `moveToDestiny`.

```
def moveToDestiny(self):
    selected_items = self.origin.curselection()
    selected = [self.origin.get(i) for i in selected_items]
    self.destiny.list_update(selected)
    self.origin.list_remove(selected)
```

Comment: I was looking for the problem in the wrong place. Putting the command in the init of the button solved the problem. Thanks for the followup example of removing items from the listbox.